# MVC Posted array of objects property is null due to field, not property

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, http-post, model-binding

Last night, i created a model containing fields of arrays of objects, which has required properties inside. Model binding was working correctly at GET request, but when its posted back, everything comes back to model excluding fields of these arrays.
Initially, I checked syntax, added ids to that objects but none of them worked. 
Model was:

```
    public class RateEditVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "IDF boş geçilemez!")]
    public int? FK_ITH_IDFID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mal Bedeli boş geçilemez!")]
    public decimal? GoodsPrice { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "İlk kur boş geçilemez!")]
    public decimal? GGBRate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mal Bedeli (TL) boş geçilemez!")]
    public decimal? GoodsPriceTL { get; set; }

    public RateValueHolder[] ShippingExpenseValues ;
    public RateValueHolder[] InsuranceExpenseValues;
    public RateValueHolder[] BankExpenseValues ;
    public RateValueHolder[] CustomsExpenseValues;
    public RateValueHolder[] LocalExpenseValues;

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Diğer Masraflar boş geçilemez!")]
    public decimal? OtherExpense { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Toplam Masraflar boş geçilemez!")]
    public decimal? TotalExpense { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Toplam Tutar boş geçilemez!")]
    public decimal? Total { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Son Kur boş geçilemez!")]
    public decimal? RateCalculated { get; set; }
}
```

and these objects was ValueHolders:

```
    public class RateValueHolder
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Boş geçilemez!")]
    public decimal? Value { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was awkward. When I changed fields to properties, everyting worked fine:

```
    public RateValueHolder[] ShippingExpenseValues { get; set; }
    public RateValueHolder[] InsuranceExpenseValues { get; set; }
    public RateValueHolder[] BankExpenseValues { get; set; }
    public RateValueHolder[] CustomsExpenseValues { get; set; }
    public RateValueHolder[] LocalExpenseValues { get; set; }
```

I think, this is a bug of default ModelBinder in MVC. If ModelBinder was looking only to Properties, it should throw errors when that Model class has that field, instead of property IMO. Because, in my view I'm using these fields as predicates so that MVC was aware of what im binding.

```
<fieldset class="col-xs-12">
<legend>Nakliye Masrafları</legend>
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ShippingExpenseValues.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(e => e.ShippingExpenseValues[i]);
}
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Its not a bug. Its by design.

Comment: So I had to find it myself. Its a bad design in my opinion. If I were the designer, I would probably throw an exception saying that "your model has {0} field, but it should be a property to bind to view"

Comment: The write your own custom `ModelBinder` (you can do anything you want)